# JOOQ: How to add an interface to record class to allow generic insertion of data

Tags: kotlin, jooq

Using Jooq 3.12.3, I am generating several Record classes that have similar fields.

I want to add a helper method that will be able to insert records of this type, using a common interface.
Something like:

```
fun insert(record: MyRecordInterface) {
    record.setField1("a")
    record.setField2("a")
    record.attach(configuration)
    record.store()
}

val record1 = Record1()
val record2 = Record2()
insert(record1)
insert(record2)
```

I am able to add an interface to the record class using matchers strategy, with the common fields accessors, but I am still missing the attach() and store() method that are used in the insert function. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define your interface like this:

```kotlin
interface MyRecordInterface<R : UpdatableRecord<R>> : UpdatableRecord<R> {}
```